# How to Embed Binaries in a Carthage Project in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, carthage

I want to add a framework in my Carthage Project which I then use in my Main project, the frame work needs to be embedded in order to work, however the Carthage project does not have the ability to embed Binaries[image: I have added an image to illustrate my problem,] There is no area to Embed binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the instructions on the Carthage github page for adding frameworks to a framework? https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#adding-frameworks-to-unit-tests-or-a-framework

The key step seems to be adding it to the "Link binary with libraries" build phase.

[image]

Comment: This did not work, since this is just linking the Binary and not embedding it